# Race condition with tow diferent account [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, race-condition

My problem is I have a website on laravel , ecomerce like with a cart and invetory ,

When i have tow customer buy the same product in same time the inventory is not exact, they have the same result and lock the product for both cart,

like if my inventory is 10 and customer order exactly in same time , they lock 10 product for each one ,

is it a race condition ?

How i can solve this kind of issue ?

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

Use shared lock function provided by the laravel. read the docs for detail
[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#pessimistic-locking)